# RegEx - вырезать средину строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как вырезать ip-адрес из From?

```
INVITE sip:92272792@192.168.123.130:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.38.16.16:5060;branch=z9hG4bK77cdade0;received=10.38.16.16;rport=5060
From: <sip:0991791311@10.38.16.16>;tag=as163688ee
To: <sip:92272792@192.168.123.130:5060>
CSeq: 102 INVITE
```

Comment: Есть наверное идеи и лучше, но я бы сделал так - ([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3} все ip - адреса в массив, а далее доставал нужный. https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=123278

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato спасибо, но мне нужно сразу переменной присвоить значение, из массива я это сделать не могу

Comment: вырезать это у вас что значит? "выдернуть" адрес из строки и сохранить его куда-нибудь, или в указанном тексте заменить удалить адрес?

Comment: @teran выдернуть и сохранить

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку поле From в SIP-протоколе стандартизировано, должно хватить проверки начала строки с "From:" и взятия текста между символами '@' и '>':
`(?<=^From:)[^@]+@\K[^>]+`.

Вернее даже так: `^From:[^@]+@\K[^>]+`. Positive Lookbehind использовать смысла нет, если после него потом всё-равно идёт последовательность сброса соответствия ('\K').

Comment: Если использовать `\K` как перезагрузку захвата, то позитивный просмотр назад можно просто заменить на `^From:`, быстродействие думаю изменится при большом массиве данных

Comment: И впрямь, как сказал @ipatev_nn, толку от positive lookbehind в таком случае никакого.

Comment: почему у всех любовь к этим исключениям вида `[^@]` или `[^>]` вместо указания жадности? `^From:.*?@([\d.]+)` вполне достаточно должно быть и куда понятнее выглядит

Comment: Для этого была причина, но об этом как-нибудь в другой раз.